# Add a character in a N position of a CSV's specific column using mac terminal

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

I have a csv with electoral results

```
PARTY1,00000003,01546,0020,PARTY2,00000001,02315,0022,PARTY3,00000000,00000,0006,
```

2nd column after the party name is vote percentage (01546 ... 02315...).

Is there a way to add a dot (.) using Mac terminal between the 3rd and 4rt character of a specific column in order to have this output:

```
PARTY1,00000003,015.46,0020,PARTY2,00000001,023.15,0022,PARTY3,00000000,000.00,0006,
```

All percentages columns will have 5 digits. The table has more columns before and after.

I work for a local newspaper doing the printed layout. I don't have much experience coding. Just some basic HTML and JS.

We will receive from the electoral authority several csv (one for each province).

I know how to manage this data with a spreadsheet app (excel, libre office). But I want to avoid them, if possible, as I see there are some actions I usually do (merging, deleting columns, adding headers) could be done faster and easier via Terminal.

I'm new to terminal commands. I've found here and there some very useful commands (cat for concatenation csv from several areas in one and cut for extracting columns I need) but nothing about inserting characters (except if they go at the beginning of a line)

My output data will go to Datawrapper or Carto, as an interactive map, and likely to Qgis to do a merge with a shp and generate a pdf for the newspaper.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: What should `00000` be transformed into? `00.00` or `0`?

Comment: I've added my tests. I know how to do this with a spreadsheet app (excel, libre office). But I want to avoid them, if possible. 
I'm new to terminal commands and I've found some very useful (cat for concatenation csv from several areas in one and cut for extracting columns I need). Final output will be a map, with a tooltip showing something like "party1: 15.46% / Party3: 0.00% etc". So, transformation, as I see it, it's just inserting a character in a 5 character string.

Comment: Where are you sending your data that you want formatted? Is it to another file or piped directly to an application?

Comment: please update your Q to include the important information you have included in the comment above. The proper form for a Q is 1. small sample input (check), 2. required output from that sample input (not found) 3. Code/error messages from your attempt to solve the problem (not found). 4. other thoughts concerns about the problem.(check(ish)). Basically, you want code/data that people can cut and paste to their terminal. Given the sample data you have shown, *nix utilities work much better on line/tab separated data, rather than CSV. (lines for each record, tabs in between each field). ....

Comment: If you can't get the current source of data to output in a *nix friendly format, then the first step is to write a conversion filter that does make the data usable. In either case, work thru the [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and update your Q with your best attempt to solve the problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I've updated my question with all details I have. Unfortunately, I can't show you any coding attempt as I'm unable to go deeper in the awk tutorial. I came to Stack to ask a temptative question about if this insertion was possible or not. I know how to do this in Excel.

It was an attempt to try a new (and possibly faster) way to do a task that it's not properly what I've to do at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=3; i<=NF; i=i+4) $i=sprintf("%.2f",$i/100)}1' file
```

Output:

```
PARTY1,00000003,15.46,0020,PARTY2,00000001,23.15,0022,PARTY3,00000000,0.00,0006,
```

**Update:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=3; i<=NF; i=i+4) $i=substr($i,1,3)"."substr($i,4,2)}1' file
```

Output:

```
PARTY1,00000003,015.46,0020,PARTY2,00000001,023.15,0022,PARTY3,00000000,000.00,0006,
```